Flink Table sink by Kafka doesn't printed TUMBLE result
When I used Flink's SQL to perform window calculations on the data pushed by Kafka, I did not receive any results.
This is the data I inputted into Kafka:
{"user_id": 1, "job_id": "beer", "ts": "2019-12-12 00:00:01"}
{"user_id": 1, "job_id": "diaper", "ts": "2019-12-12 00:00:02"}
{"user_id": 2, "job_id": "pen", "ts": "2019-12-12 00:00:04"}
{"user_id": 2, "job_id": "rubber", "ts": "2019-12-12 00:00:06"}
{"user_id": 3, "job_id": "rubber", "ts": "2019-12-12 00:00:05"}
{"user_id": 4, "job_id": "beer", "ts": "2019-12-12 00:00:08"}

final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
EnvironmentSettings settings = EnvironmentSettings.newInstance().inStreamingMode().build();
StreamTableEnvironment tEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env, settings);

tEnv.executeSql(
            "CREATE TABLE orders (\n"
        + "  user_id INT,\n"
        + "  job_id STRING,\n"
        + "  ts TIMESTAMP(3),\n"
        + "  WATERMARK FOR ts AS ts - INTERVAL '3' SECOND\n"
        + ") WITH (\n"
        + " 'connector' = 'kafka',\n"
        + " 'topic' = 'reqLimit1',\n"
        + " 'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092',\n"
        + " 'properties.group.id' = 'flinkGroup',\n"
        + " 'format' = 'json',\n"
        + " 'scan.startup.mode' = 'latest-offset'\n"
        + ")"
);

This is the data I inputted into Kafka:
{"user_id": 1, "job_id": "beer", "ts": "2019-12-12 00:00:01"}
{"user_id": 1, "job_id": "diaper", "ts": "2019-12-12 00:00:02"}
{"user_id": 2, "job_id": "pen", "ts": "2019-12-12 00:00:04"}
{"user_id": 2, "job_id": "rubber", "ts": "2019-12-12 00:00:06"}
{"user_id": 3, "job_id": "rubber", "ts": "2019-12-12 00:00:05"}
{"user_id": 4, "job_id": "beer", "ts": "2019-12-12 00:00:08"}

The group by here can be printed
String query = "SELECT \n" +
        "    date_format(ts, '%Y%m%d') as cdate,\n" +
        "       user_id,\n" +
        "    sum(user_id) as total\n" +
        "FROM orders\n" +
        "GROUP BY date_format(ts, '%Y%m%d'), user_id\n";
tEnv.sqlQuery(query).execute().print();

+----+--------------------------------+-------------+-------------+
| op |                          cdate |     user_id |       total |
+----+--------------------------------+-------------+-------------+
| +I |                     %2019%0%12 |           2 |           2 |
| -U |                     %2019%0%12 |           2 |           2 |
| +U |                     %2019%0%12 |           2 |           4 |

but this group by not any printed
String query ="SELECT\n"
        + "  user_id,\n"
        + "  COUNT(*) jobs\n"
        + "FROM orders\n"
        + "GROUP BY user_id,TUMBLE(ts, INTERVAL '5' SECOND)";

